# ActiveMQ inactive broker

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, activemq-classic

The problem is that I have defined some broker uri which could be inactive.
Then `createConnection` from `ActiveMQConnectionFactory` doesn't throw any exception. I need to handle such situation and if `createConnection` doesn't work because of uri won't be available then I should mark my service as unhealthy.

```
boolean healthy = true;
Connection conn = null;
try {
    final ActiveMQConnectionFactory factory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("failover:(tcp://localhost:8080)?jms.prefetchPolicy.all=0&initialReconnectDelay=1000&maxReconnectDelay=30000&maxReconnectAttempts=20");
    conn = factory.createConnection(this.userName, this.password);
} catch (JMSException e) {
    healthy = false;
} finally {
    if (conn != null) {
        try {
            conn.close();
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            healthy = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: failover:(tcp://localhost:8080)?jms.prefetchPolicy.all=0&initialReconnectDelay=1000&maxReconnectDelay=30000&maxReconnectAttempts=20

Comment: Yes exactly, this is what happened. No I didn't try to create session. I will try this and let know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want create connection to fail with an exception but you are also using the failover transport?  Doesn't that seem at odds to you?

The failover transport usage is resulting in the create to succeed because the failover transport is doing exactly what you asked it to do which is to try and establish a connection repeatedly until the configured number of attempts is made.  Calling a method like create session will block and eventually throw an error once the failover transport gives up.  Alternately you could set an exception listener that will be signalled once the connection is closed because the failover transport runs out of reconnect attempts.

Comment: Thank you, the exception listener is probably what I was searching for